# Make dynamic variable name

Tags: javascript

I need to change this code

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var $name = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();
</script>
```

to include dynamically `('.gallery1 a'),('.gallery2 a'),('.gallery3 a')`
any help please

Comment: *change this **incomplete and invalid** code* ... maybe learn how to concatenate strings

Comment: i need to change just this piece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam's answer is basically correct.  Here is a concrete example of how to use it.  Instead of writing repetitive code like this:

```
$(function(){
    var $name = $('.gallery1 a').simpleLightbox();
    var $name = $('.gallery2 a').simpleLightbox();
    var $name = $('.gallery3 a').simpleLightbox();
    // etc. etc.
});
```

With his function you can write this instead:

```
$(function(){
    function applySimpleLightboxToAChild(dynamicGallary){
        var $name = $("." + dynamicGallary + " a").simpleLightbox();
    };

    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        applySimpleLightboxToAChild('gallery' + i);
    }
});
```

Which successfully abstracts away any repetitive code - taking advantage of the fact that the `+` operator in Javascript converts numbers to strings, so that `'gallery' + i` is converted to `gallery1` when i = 1, and so on.  (If you prefer, you can use a template literal like in frankmackey's answer: instead of `'gallery' + i`, you would write `` `gallery${i}` ``.)

Comment: yes i need your  second answer because i dont know what  is the number,because its variable ,its working thank you very very much but if   i made i<= big number, is this affect the site  performance?

Comment: If it's really huge, it might affect site performance.  The browser isn't exactly a high-performance computing environment, so you probably want to set up the site so that the user can view a small number at once by searching or filtering.

Answer (score 3):

Send the name to the function like this

```
function yourFunction (dynamicGallary){
    var $name = $("." + dynamicGallary + " a").simpleLightbox();
}

yourFunction("gallary1");
```

Comment: whatt should i write in the place of "dynamicGallery'' sorry i am a  student

Comment: Don't write anything. You send what you want to the function like that 
yourFunction("gallary1"); 
yourFunction("gallary2");
yourFunction("gallary3");

Comment: if you give me the code for copy and paste ,it will be very nice andam

Comment: i need the code to include  from gallery1 to gallery infinity

Comment: You clearly don't understand me or I don't understand you. Write in your native language.

Comment: look this script make gallery for any pictures found inside  div which has class"gallery" but the name of div in my script is php variable brings the name of class from the  database so my div name may be gallery1 or gallery99 or gallery100000 ,so i need to make this script make gallery for

Comment: any div with class name gallery+number

Comment: thanks  andam   you are right but  i needed the   additiion of jcarpenter because i dont know the number

Comment: @Ali I get it now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but generally speaking, reflective programming in JavaScript is not encouraged due to security and efficiency reasons.

So assuming these gallery class elements are all the same in terms of format, excluding their content, you could change all their classes to `.gallery`. Then,
you could use the JQuery selector to get all the `<a>` elements inside those with `class="gallery"` attributes and retrieve them like this using the nth-child selector:

```
function getName(i) {
    return $(`.gallery a:nth-child(${i})`).simpleLightbox();
}
```

EDIT:

Seeing the discussion on the above answer, here is another solution.

```
function getName(i) {
    return $(`.gallery${i} a`).simpleLightbox();
}
```

Comment: `i` would be in place of 1 in `'gallery1'`.

Comment: i will try that

Comment: Be sure to use template strings if you are going to follow these examples. They are the tilde keys (aka `)

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalLength = 5; // get your length by class name or Id name
for(var i = 0; i < totalLength; i++)
{
    var myVar = '.gallary'+i;
    $(myVar+' a').simpleLightbox();
}
```

Comment: First get the length by using class or Id and create dynamic variable name using for loop